# Getting data from an object with a generated key

Tags: javascript, json

Lets assume I have an object like this.

```
var foo = {
  "dfsghasdgsad":{
    "name":"bob",
    "age":"27"
  }
};
```

foo will always have just one object but the key is generated. How do I retrieve "bob" and "27" in a situation where I won't know what the generated key name will be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Object.keys`:

```
var key = Object.keys(foo)[0];
var name = foo[key].name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys` to get a list of the keys:

```
var name = foo[Object.keys(foo)[0]].name;
```